# The uniform distribution of p-value under null hypothesis

Tags: p-value, uniform-distribution

Suppose z is a continuous random variable and follows a certain distribution

We define φ(x)=p(z>=x), where x is a continuous random variable

It can be proved that the continuous random variable φ(x) follows the uniform distribution:
p(φ(x)<=φ(ξ))
=p(x>=ξ)
=φ(x)

However, the distribution of φ(x) should depend on the distribution of x but the proof procedure has nothing to do with it. That's what I am confused about.

To elaborate on my point, I am confused about the process of getting different values of φ(x) and then the distribution of it. The value of φ(x) really depends on the value of x, which is not specified in the proof.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Careful: "it can be proved" is incorrect unless you assume $Z$ follows a *continuous* distribution.

Comment: @jbowman Thank you, I read the post carefully. I think I understand how to extend the formula to the null hypothesis. What I am confused about is really the process of getting different value of 1-CDF.

Comment: @whuber, thank you! edited the question

Comment: I don't understand the question, because "$x$" refers to a *number* but you write as if it had a "distribution."  Note, too, that $\phi(X)$ is not a continuous random variable unless $X$ is.  You also refer several times to "the proof" but you haven't exhibited anything that looks like a proof.

Comment: @whuber The proof I referred to is: p(φ(x)<=φ(ξ)) =p(x>=ξ) =φ(x). x should be a random variable. For example, in the regression setting, x should be the test-statistics through repeated sampling.

Comment: In that case your definition of $\varphi$ is incorrect.  You appear to be trying to define the survival function of the random variable $Z$ and in that definition $x$ *must* be a number.  The reason I see no kind of proof here is that you provide only a sequence of equalities but (a) not all terms are defined (what is "$\xi,$' for instance?) and (b) no reasoning is provided.  Both (a) and (b) are essential parts of proofs.

Comment: Thank you, do you mean x should be a fixed number? But x is the independent variable in the function. May you explain more? thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102921/discussion-between-yuan-and-whuber).